# How do I get the total quantity of "collections" in my array?

Tags: php

I have an array that contains an item's ID and it's quantity. The quantity is basically how many times an item has been placed in the collection. So item `1` is in the collection ten times, item `2` is in the collection two times, and item `9` is one time.

So this means that I have one full collection, because item `9` is only in there once.

```
$data = [
    1 => 10,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 2,
    4 => 2,
    5 => 2,
    6 => 2,
    7 => 2,
    8 => 2,
    9 => 1
];
```

Below: I now have two collections, because item `9` is in twice.

```
$data = [
    1 => 10,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 2,
    4 => 2,
    5 => 2,
    6 => 2,
    7 => 2,
    8 => 2,
    9 => 2
];
```

In the next instance I still only have two collections, because item `3` is only in there two times. hopefully it's making sense what I'm trying to do.

```
$data = [
    1 => 10,
    2 => 5,
    3 => 2,
    4 => 5,
    5 => 8,
    6 => 4,
    7 => 4,
    8 => 5,
    9 => 6
];
```

The array isn't fixed to 9 items either, it can be any amount.

This should be fairly simple, but I've been racking my brain over this for quite some time, and it's just stuck; I'm too close to the problem now. I originally thought I could divide the total number of items by the quantity but that didn't work.

How do I do this so that I can loop through the array and see how many full collections I have?

Comment: Based on how you've described the issue, couldn't we simply get the lowest number in the array? Example: $min = min($data);

Comment: @KadeM.The problem with that (I believe) is if one of the items is empty, it'll still show the lowest number, instead of `0`.

Comment: But if the item is empty, that would mean you have zero collections right? To my knowledge, min() should return 0 for a null value.

Comment: @KadeM. Yep, you got it. I was testing with an actual collection from Laravel and it wasn't showing a 0, it was showing the lowest int, which was wrong. Make this an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Have a great day Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on how you've described the issue, couldn't we simply get the lowest number in the array? Example:

```
$min = min($data);
```

In the event of a null/empty value, min() should return 0.

Comment: For anyone else who comes along: I was using an array with assigned keys, and this was also causing an issue and displaying the incorrect results. I had to remove the assigned key and then everything started working.